# What is the use of stateConnectionString in sessionState in Web.config?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, web-config, sessionstate-timeout

I'm using VS 2005 for web forms.

Looking at the web.config I see a stateConnectionString attribute.

- Is this really needed?
- When is this needed?
- How is this used?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean sqlConnectionString attribute?  If you do then it is used if you set the state server mode to SqlServer for usage in a web farm scenario.  It is the box running the Sql Server for the session state store.